# Openness of a subset a compact $T_1$ topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact and $T_1$ topological space and  let $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$ such that  for each $a\in A$, $\{a\}$ is open in $A$ (as a subspace of $X$). Can we deduce that $A$ is open in $X$?

Comment: It makes no sense to say that a point $a$ is open in a set; do you mean that $\{a\}$ is open in $A$ for each $a\in A$? If so, the answer is clearly *no*: just consider the set $A=\{0\}$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Brian M. Scott :Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Discrete subsets are hardly ever open, infinite or not: in fact, while it is true that metric spaces might have finite balls, in the typical case of use you don't want them to.

Comment: $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $X = [0, 1]$, and let $A = \{ \tfrac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Then $X$ is compact and $T_1$, $A$ is infinite, $\{a\}$ is open in $A$ for each $a \in A$, but $A$ is not open in $X$.